# Low voice in asterisk playback function

Tags: asterisk, volume

We have "Interactive Voice Response (IVR)" set-up using asterisk PBX that interacts with callers, gathers information and routes calls to the appropriate recipient.

We have used Playback function in asterisk to play the IVR but the issue is that when we play the audio file, the volume is very low i.e it is not audible.

We have used the on-line tool "http://www.text2speech.org/" which help us to increase the intensity of the volume but asterisk needs a file with only "8 K Hz" sampling rate which decrease the volume intensity and again it is not audible.

Is there any tool specific for "8000 K Hz" audio file generation with high intensity volume that it should be visible clearly audible. Please help us in any other technique.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) It's one of the best tool for sound along with ffmpeg.

I don't know your platform but here is a windows command:

```
sox.exe "input" -r 8000 -c 1 -t ul -w "output"
```

Asterisk works better with ulaw files, the command above will give you a frequency of `8000kHz`.

Comment: Can you give the command for Linux. I have already tried the below command in Linux and it decreased the volume by half:

----
sox input.mp3 -r 8000 -c 1 output.gsm
------

Comment: @RahulPahuja use `-v` flag to increase volume tweak it as needed `sox -v1 input.mp3 -r 8000 -c 1 output.gsm` or you can use `-G` for automatic ajustments

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 options

1) Change file to be louder. You can use sox or [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/?lang=en)(free editor for windows)

2) Change in dialplan volume using [VOLUME](http://das-asterisk-buch.de/1.6/functions-volume.html) function

Comment: I have tried to increase the volume by audacity and sox but while converting to GSM extension(with 8 KHz frequency), volume is decreasing due to clipping.